# r: Obtaining final cluster results in a table/ dataframe when using hclust()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I am conducting a hierarchical cluster analysis by using `hclust()`

The code looks like this:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
```

Now, all I need is to get a table (or something equivalent) which contains all clusters and the observations (by their rowname, NOT number) which belong to them so that I can save it to some overall file/dataframe - e.g. Excel. (I want to run the hclust several times with different methods, variables and evaluate the results in the end.)

I now, its probably pretty easy, but I am stuck somehow... do you have any advice?

Ps.: I would also like to know how this works when using `kmeans()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hclust` does not give you the cluster groups. you can use `cutree` to make cluster them. 
So, if you want to cluster them in three groups;

```
cutree(hc,3)
```

if you want dataframe,

```
data.frame(cutree(hc,3))
```

for kmeans,

```
km<-kmeans(USArrests,3)

km$centers
```